# Reactjs - how to access self propertie?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`<Component key="1" onClick={this.callThisFunction(???)}/>`

So, onClick function I would like to call another function as pass the key value "1" as parameter. How can I achieve this ? Thanks.

Comment: Is the key value a variable or hardcoded?

Comment: I have a 'list' of this <Component> being generated. Each one will have a unique key, that's incremeting eg:. 1,2,3,4 ... . And it will not be changed.
I would like to know wich of it was pressed. That's what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't per se. The event handler doesn't know anything about the component it is attached to. (It might have an `event` object which will tell it about the HTML DOM element that raised the click event).

Put the value (i.e. the key) into a variable and capture it with a closure instead.

```
const key = "1";
const clickHandler = () => this.callThisFunction(key);
return <Component key={key} onClick={clickHandler} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the function/arrow block inside the onClick property:

```
<Component 
    key={key} 
    onClick={(ev) => this.callThisFunction(key)}/>
```